# Java 8 stream- convert List<Integer[]> to Map<Integer,List<Integer>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert the `List<Integer[]>` to `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>`.
The `Integer[]` is of size two. `Integer[0]` is the key of the map and `Integer[1]` will be the value of the map.

Let's take an example. The input values are:

```
List<Integer[]> a=new ArrayList<>(5);
a.add(new Integer[] {1,2});
a.add(new Integer[] {1,3});
a.add(new Integer[] {1,15});
a.add(new Integer[] {2,11});
a.add(new Integer[] {2,7});
```

And the resulted output map will have two keys, 1 and 2.

The value of key 1 are 2,3 and 15.

The value of key 2 are 11 and 7.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: Try playing around with [`Collectors.GroupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I just want to use java stream to convert the List<Integer[]> to Map<Integer,List<Integer>>.

Comment: What do you want as Result? Map<Integer, List<Integer>>?

Comment: and why are you not just using java streams?

Comment: @mwe, Because I want to use parallel stream after that, I need to do further processing and collect the records on primary key basis.

Comment: You shouldn't mix up arrays and `List`s.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a stream that groups collected results on the first element of the array:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> gouped = a.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], 
             Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1], Collectors.toList())));
```

And that map is `{1=[2, 3, 15], 2=[11, 7]}`

Comment: Thank you so much @ernest_k, I forgot to use the Collectors.mapping and that's why not able to get the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
a.stream().forEach(t -> {
                map.computeIfAbsent(t[0], ArrayList::new);
                map.get(t[0]).add(t[1]);
            });
```